# Can you force an app to use Cleartype?

Tags: windows, fonts, cleartype, anti-aliasing

The app we use for development (**CodeWright 7**) is quite old and has Cleartype turned off by default. A newer version has the option to turn on font smoothing, but I'm stuck with this version and upgrading is not an option for me.

Is there a way to force the app to use Cleartype?

Comment: I thought Cleartype is a system-wide property, not per-application. Does CodeWright 7 actively turn it off for the system?

Comment: It's not system-wide. The best example is Safari; you can choose between Windows default and Apple specific font aliasing.

Comment: Is this on XP or Vista?

Comment: XP, but I'm sure it would have the same behavior in Vista or 7 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to use Brief way back when, and when my project team decided to use CodeWright (which can emulate Brief) I was looking forward to it. But I had a really serious problem with CodeWright: all fonts looked ugly in it.

Google newgroups to the rescue. I created a new registry DWORD value (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\CodeWright\Customize\FontQuality) and set it to 0.

Now fonts in CodeWright look beautiful (at least in Windows XP using ClearType).

Comment: I looked into that as well, but I don't have administrator rights on my work PC. Do you know of a way to do it as a limited user?

Comment: @alex, you should ask "how can I get admin right ?" :)

Comment: @Revolver out of the question, unfortunately.

Comment: @farnhamtech +1 for liking CodeWright (it's a nice program, very powerful) and for offering a good suggestion.

Comment: You do not need special permissions to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE does need admin rights.)  If regedit is disabled, that means you only have to find another way to edit the registry.

Comment: IF you cannot access regedit then try a freeware program - there are loads
http://regeditx.software.informer.com/

This program i use a couple of times, gives you access to regedit and also a couple of new options to make it easier

Comment: @farnhamtech Yeah, but I need an administrator account for that :). Kind of kills the purpose of running it.

Comment: @Kevin Panko Do you know of any methods to edit the registry, other than regedit (disabled, unfortunately)

Comment: @farnhamtech I'll accept your answer because I'm almost certain this is the way to do it. I'll ask for administrative rights to apply this fix and hopefully I'll have Cleartype where it rightfully belongs :)

Comment: I used to use Lavasoft Reghance.  It seems to be a part of Ad-aware now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have many chances here. The only trick I can think about right now, is that you locate the font file used in CodeWright 7, get his name, and give it to a more readable font.

Comment: I can use any font I want, but most of them look terrible without Cleartype.

Answer (score 0):

CodeWright 7 almost certainly uses GDI as its rendering mechanism. This doesn't support some newer ClearType features and text may look different to you from other applications.

There is no way to change this, that I am aware of. You can probably make some adjustments to the rendering of GDI-based applications through ClearType, according to this text from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType#ClearType_in_GDI)

Comment: I was expecting GDI to be used, but I thought there was a way of overriding that, to just force it use Cleartype.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open notepad and paste this into it:

```
[Version] 
Signature="$Chicago$" 
Provider=Helper 

[DefaultInstall] 
AddReg=UnhookRegKey 

[UnhookRegKey] 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\batfile\shell\open\command,,,"""%1"" %*" 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\comfile\shell\open\command,,,"""%1"" %*" 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\exefile\shell\open\command,,,"""%1"" %*" 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\piffile\shell\open\command,,,"""%1"" %*" 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\regfile\shell\open\command,,,"regedit.exe "%1"" 
HKLM, Software\CL@ssES\scrfile\shell\open\command,,,"""%1"" %*" 
HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System,DisableRegistryTools,0x00000020,0
```

Then click on File > Save, save it to your desktop as "RegFix.inf" without the quotes of course.

On your desktop, right click on your newly created RegFix.inf and click install. 
Hopefully, that will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution, but I need administrator rights on my work machine before I can do this.

Comment: They wont allow you to create a inf and install it! they like to keep their hands on the reigns dont they?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Mactype](http://www.mactype.net/). It's an [open source](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype) program that replaces Windows font renderer and has an option to **enable/disable font smoothing for a specific program**. Support is best for GDI applications, while DirectWrite support is still being improved

[image: mactype]